# Append new subscription to existing session in BLPAPI

Tags: python, blpapi

Is there any way to append new subscription to already running session or do I need to terminate that session and then create new subscription with that new additional ticker to subscribe?

All examples from SDK have ticker predefined up front and I can't find anything if what I'm looking for is even possible.

From Python example:

```
def subscribe(p_identity):
    subscriptionOptions = []
    fieldList = []
    fieldList.append("SUBSCRIPTION_DATA")
    fieldList.append("LAST_PRICE")
    fieldList.append("BID")
    fieldList.append("ASK")
    fieldList.append("EID")
    fieldList.append("MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE")
    fieldList.append("MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE")
    fieldList.append("IS_DELAYED_STREAM")
    subscriptionOptions1 = []
    cInfo = CorrelationInfo("BBG0013S8C89")
    cId = blpapi.CorrelationId(cInfo)
    g_subscriptions.add(cInfo.getTopic(), fieldList, subscriptionOptions1, cId)
    subscriptionOptions2 = []
    cInfo = CorrelationInfo("BBG0013SHH88")
    cId = blpapi.CorrelationId(cInfo)
    g_subscriptions.add(cInfo.getTopic(), fieldList, subscriptionOptions2, cId)
    subscriptionOptions3 = []
    cInfo = CorrelationInfo("JPY CURNCY")
    cId = blpapi.CorrelationId(cInfo)
    g_subscriptions.add(cInfo.getTopic(), fieldList, subscriptionOptions3, cId)
    subscriptionOptions4 = []
    cInfo = CorrelationInfo("SPX 5 C4450 INDEX")
    cId = blpapi.CorrelationId(cInfo)
    g_subscriptions.add(cInfo.getTopic(), fieldList, subscriptionOptions4, cId)
    # Subscriptions will start after authorization is successful
```

and then call it as

```
 session.subscribe(subscriptions, identity)
```

Create session for async events

```
session = blpapi.Session(session_options, eventHandler.processEvent)
```

where `subscribe` is part of `processEvent` and it happens before connection to authorization service

```
    if not session.openService("//blp/apiauth"):
        _logger.error("Failed to open //blp/apiauth")
        return
```

Comment: You can subscribe to several tickers within the same session, in one or several calls. Just call session.subscribe() more than once.

Comment: @assylias That makes sense but then how can I append it in already running code? I was looking at Python and Java examples and all of them are using lists/arrays and are adding them there up front then added to the subscription. I have updated OP with some example. Also is there any way to check what is already subscribed? If so I can put `session.subscribe()` is some loop to read tickers and options from a file or a DB.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking - simply create a new subscription object; `session.subscribe(subscriptions)` and then `session.subscribe(otherSubscriptions)`? I don't think you can query the subscription which are "live", you need to keep track of what tickers you have subscribed to and unsubscribe them as and when required.

Comment: @assylias I have added more to the OP. My question is that if I can authorize session (as a global?) with an empty subscription (as the part of `eventHandler.processEvent`) for the session and then add tickers as you have described?

Comment: Here are the steps: start the session with an Event Handler, authenticate as required, call subscribe as many times as you want (each call passes a Subscription object which is supposed to have a unique CorrelationID). In the Event Handler, listen to "SUBSCRIPTION_DATA" events and read the message's CorrelationID to know which subscription request the data relates to.